# Database Lookup Cache in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Lately, I have seen Pentaho behaving strangely as it sometimes doesn't return the correct value as a lookup result. I have enabled cache in the lookup steps.

- How can I clear the cache once in a while through command line?
- I am trying to locate the db.cache file on the Linux box where we have Pentaho Community Edition installed but couldn't find it. I used the below command just to be sure:

  find -type f -regex ".*/.*db-cache.*"

Any ideas on how you deal with these issues will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you disable cache(Uncheck box)?
Why don't you use another step like merge join, lookup?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question what specific PDI step or steps you are using.  Database Value Lookup behaves differently depending on whether cache is checked:  a cached lookup is done in Java and is case-sensitive; an un-cached lookup is done in SQL and is case-insensitive.